# javabean to xmltype string

Tags: java, xml, javabeans

I am trying to store java string object in javabean and trying to convert it xml format.It is stored successfully but whenever i tried to get data from java bean.i received in simple string format not in xml format.

Please help me.

My code is below for javabean:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = {"username", "password"})
public class newBean {
@XmlElement(name = "username", required = true)
protected String username;

@XmlElement(name = "password", required = true)
protected String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need XML output from your bean in J2SE enviroment, you can try this:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(newBean.class);

newBean bean = new newBean();

bean.setUsername("user");
bean.setPassword("secret");

JAXBElement<newBean> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Main.newBean>(new QName("name"), newBean.class, bean);

Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, writer);

String result = writer.toString();

// print result to console
System.out.println(result);
```

but with @XmlRootElement anotation it may be easier:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(newBean.class);

newBean bean = new newBean();

bean.setUsername("user");
bean.setPassword("secret");

Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(bean, writer);

String result = writer.toString();

// print result to console
System.out.println(result);
```

note that with @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD), you can also omit getters and setters:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = { "username", "password" })
public static class newBean {
    @XmlElement(name = "username", required = true)
    protected String username;

    @XmlElement(name = "password", required = true)
    protected String password;
}
```